# What is the correct or most appropriate way to address phantom or untraceable 404 errors showing up in a website audit?

Tags: redirects, 404, iis

Currently I am running my site through neilpatel's website for the purposes of an audit on SEO - the analyzer continues to return a 404 error that i cannot find anywhere, following this URL structure exactly:

https://www.example.com/case-studies.html

Although i have set up a permanent 301 redirect on the Microsoft IIS system hosting the website (these seem to be housed under the VM's Rewrite module and not the HTTP redirect as i had thought they may be) which now sends any requests for https://www.example.com/case-studies.html to https://www.example.com/insights/case-studies.html, I feel that I may either be doing it wrong, or missing something fundamental in being able to identify where this 404 is coming from. Part of this stems from the fact that i do not know how to frame the question correctly to search engines.

I have checked my sitemap for this anomaly, and trawled all of my HTML content as well to see if it is hiding in there.

Could anyone advise as to whether i am making a simple or stupid mistake here?

Comment: I've never used the particular tool that you are trying.   Every SEO audit tool worth its salt will tell you which pages problems are found on.   I'd look in the 404 report to see if there is a referring page listed.

Comment: There is not, no. I have redirected these three but with no indication of where they were coming from.

Comment: I'd use a different SEO audit tool then.